# I can't change anything in my CSS, nothing takes effect

Tags: html

This is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<header>
  <div id="navbar">
  <div id="Home"><h1>Home</h1> </div>
</div>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#navbar{
  background-color: #666666;
  text-align: right;
}
```

All the HTML I write is fine but whenever I try to change something with CSS nothing happens, please help.

Comment: Where does your HTML reference your CSS?

Comment: there's no reference to the style.css from within your index.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your head tags you need to add:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

the href may need to be adjusted with the path of style.css,  If it is in the same folder as index.html it should be fine

I would recommend reading over this website, here is a direct link to your current issue: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: Thank you I've been trying to figure this out for a while and it was so simple

Comment: if it works accept the answer so others know this worked

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below between your `<head></head>` tag.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```